# Where did manu tell "Achaara heenan na punanti Veda"?

Tags: vedas, practice, manu-smriti, manu

Recently while hearing about the importance of sadhachara, I encountered the following interesting statement

> **Achaara heenan na punanti Veda**
>
> Vedas cannot purify the person who does not perform acharas

It is a very useful statement for day-to-day life as many people tend to study scriptures without following acharas. After hearing it, I started searching for the source(s) and found many scriptures.

> आचारहीनं न पुनन्ति वेदा यद्यप्यधीता: सह  षड्भिरंगै:।
>
> छन्दांस्येनं मृत्युकाले त्यजन्ति नीडं शकुंता इव जातपक्षा:
>
> (वसिष्ठ स्मृति 6/3; देवी भागवत 11/2/1) [ref](https://www.punjabkesari.in/mantra-bhajan-arti/news/scriptures-483308)
>
> Achaara heenan na punanti Veda
> yadyapyadheetah saha shatbhirangaih,
> shilpam hi Vedadhyayanam Dwijaanam
> vrutam Smrutam Brahmana lakshmanam tu
>
> [[9, Skanda Shashthi Vrata, Bhavishya Purana]](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=9)

So, Vasishta smriti, Devi Bagahavatham, and Bhavishya Purana contain the verse. But on [this site](http://sanskrit-ki-duniya.blogspot.com/2016/07/acharyasri-rajesh.html?m=1), I read that Manu also told the same.

> आचार हीनो न पुनन्ति वेदाः (Achara Hino Na Punanthi Vedah) says Manu.

Is it present in Manusmriti? If yes, in which chapter? If not, where did Manu tell this?

---

*Note*: I didn't validate personally the ref part of Vashishtha Smriti and Devi Bhagavatam.